# $a^2-b^2 = k$, $ab = l$ for fixed integer $k,l$ when $a,b$ are both integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, integer-programming

Let us fix integers $k,l$. Let all numbers be integers.

Now we want integer $a,b$ to satisfy:
$$a^2-b^2 = k, \,\,\,2ab = l.$$

We want to maximize the number of possible $(a,b)$. In order to do this, how should I select $k,l$?

In other words, is it possible to select $k,l$ such that the number of possible $(a,b)$ is not limited to some finite number?

Comment: Can't do much, these are hyperbolas except in degenerate cases.

Comment: If $l$ is non-zero then $2ab=l$ only has finitely many integral solutions, so then $l=0$ and all solutions must be of the form $a=0$ or $b=0$, but then $a^2-b^2=k$ will only have finitely many solutions for a fixed $k$.

Comment: For the system, there are $2$ integer solutions or none.

Answer (score 1):

Write the first as $4a^2k=4a^4-l^2$ This has at most four solutions.

Comment: can you expand a little on it?

Comment: @NikosM.: It is a fourth degree polynomial, so there will be at most four roots.  They may not all be integers.  As it is a quadratic in $a^2$, the roots will come in pairs of opposite signs.

Comment: Thanks, i meant expand on the derivation of the expression $4a^2k=4a^4-l^2$

Comment: @NikosM: I substituted $b=\frac l{2a}$ in the first and multiplied by $4a^2$ to clear fractions

Comment: Now is clear thanx, i was confused since it was mentioned "write the first" and i could not see it

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it by first determining $a^2, b^2$ using a straightforward quadratic identity.

$$a^2-b^2=k$$

$$(a^2+b^2)^2=(a^2-b^2)^2-4a^2b^2=k^2-l^2$$So that  $$a^2+b^2=\sqrt{k^2-l^2}$$[Have to take the positive square root if you are in $\mathbb R$]

This system is easy to solve and you should see that $a^2$ and $b^2$ are determined by $k$ and $l$. Then the only choice is the sign of $a$ and $b$. Remembering that $l$ is fixed, you should find two solutions except when $(k,l)=(0,0)$.